# Properties of algebraic vector fields which generates a $\mathbb{C^*}$ action

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, algebraic-groups

My question is rather vague and I apologize. Let $X$ be a smooth quasi-projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$. I am interested in whether there are homological properties which distinguish algebraic vector fields which generate a $\mathbb{C}^*$ action from an arbitrary algebraic vector field $Z$.